# ggplot breaks as date month and day without year, show labels for chosen dates in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking for a way to add labels on the x-axis of a line graph for specified dates that are the same each year.

I have a nested list with dates and river streamflow data (Flow) in different river reaches RCH (here for simplicity just reach no. 910):

```
Flowtest <- list( tibble(date=as.Date(c("2015/08/01","2015/08/02","2015/08/03","2015/08/04",
                                       "2015/08/05","2015/08/06","2015/08/07"), format="%Y/%m/%d"),
                                Flow=c(123, 170, 187, 245, 679, 870, 820),
                                RCH=c(910)), 
                 tibble(date=as.Date(c("2016/08/01","2016/08/02","2016/08/03","2016/08/04",
                                       "2016/08/05","2016/08/06","2016/08/07"), format="%Y/%m/%d"),
                                Flow=c(570, 450, 780, 650, 230, 470, 340),
                                RCH=c(910)),
                 tibble(date=as.Date(c("2017/08/01","2017/08/02","2017/08/03","2017/08/04",
                                        "2017/08/05","2017/08/06","2017/08/07"), format="%Y/%m/%d"),
                                 Flow=c(160, 170, 670, 780, 350, 840, 850),
                                 RCH=c(910)),
                  tibble(date=as.Date(c("2018/08/01","2018/08/02","2018/08/03","2018/08/04",
                                        "2018/08/05","2018/08/06","2018/08/07"), format="%Y/%m/%d"),
                                 Flow=c(120, 780, 820, 580, 870, 870, 840),
                                RCH=c(910)))
```

I've created a function that creates a graph for each year and plot on it Flows coming from various reaches (here for simplicity I just used a single reach 910). I want to add on the x-axis labels for several specified dates (month and day) that are the same each year. I didn't know how to make it work for every year so instead, I've only added it for year 2015:

```
test_line_plot <- function (x) {
  ggplot(x, aes(date, Flow, group = RCH)) +
    geom_line() + 
    facet_wrap( ~ format(date, "%Y"))+
   scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d", 
         breaks = (as.Date(c("2015/08/04", "2015/08/06"))))+
    theme (panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
    coord_cartesian( ylim = c(0, 1000))
}
```

And I've applied it to my list:

```
test_plot_list <- lapply(Flowtest , test_line_plot)
library("ggpubr")
test_plot <- ggarrange(plotlist = test_plot_list, nrow = 4, ncol = 1)
plot(test_plot)
```

In the resulting graph date labels onx-axis and matching major grid lines only appear in 2015:

[image]

Where I was hoping to achieve something like the one below, where every year has the same date labels and major grid lines marking them:

[image]

How can I change the code in the function so it doesnt just apply to 2015 but also any other years in the dataset?

**Also** I don't understand why the graph for 2015 is smaller then the other graphs...

I'll be thankful for help

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use a single data.frame to use facet for each year.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(lubridate)
    
    Flowtest %>%
      # Make a single data.frame from the list of data.frames
      bind_rows() %>% 
      # Create variable year
      mutate(year = year(date)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(date, Flow, group = RCH)) +
      geom_line() + 
      # Using year for facet, with free scales and a single column
      facet_wrap(~year,scales = "free", ncol = 1)+
      scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d")+
      theme (panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
      coord_cartesian( ylim = c(0, 1000))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, your suggested improvement doesn't allow me to specify dates that I would like to be marked on the x-axis of each graph for each year (eg. just 4th and 6th of August). In my actual dataset, those dates occur at various times in the year. How can this be added to the code (or changed as currently my code only applied to 2015)?

Comment: You could use `breaks` inside `scale_x_date` @JoannaOK

Comment: If you don't want to list the dates manually, you could use: `breaks <- c("0804", "0806"); years <- 2015:2018; breaks <- tibble(crossing(years,breaks),  date = ymd(paste0(years,breaks))) %>% pull(date)` and then `scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d", breaks = breaks) +`