# adding chosen dates (day and month) as x-axis labels for each year (the same every year) in ggplot scale_x_date

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking for a way to add labels on the x-axis of a line graph for specified dates that are the same each year. **The main focus here is adding chosen dates (day and month) as x-axis labels for each year (the same every year). Preferably with the use of scale_x_date.**

I have a nested list with dates and river streamflow data (Flow) in different river reaches RCH (here for simplicity just reach no. 910):

```
Flowtest <- list( tibble(date=as.Date(c("2015/08/01","2015/08/02","2015/08/03","2015/08/04",
                                       "2015/08/05","2015/08/06","2015/08/07"), format="%Y/%m/%d"),
                                Flow=c(123, 170, 187, 245, 679, 870, 820),
                                RCH=c(910)), 
                 tibble(date=as.Date(c("2016/08/01","2016/08/02","2016/08/03","2016/08/04",
                                       "2016/08/05","2016/08/06","2016/08/07"), format="%Y/%m/%d"),
                                Flow=c(570, 450, 780, 650, 230, 470, 340),
                                RCH=c(910)),
                 tibble(date=as.Date(c("2017/08/01","2017/08/02","2017/08/03","2017/08/04",
                                        "2017/08/05","2017/08/06","2017/08/07"), format="%Y/%m/%d"),
                                 Flow=c(160, 170, 670, 780, 350, 840, 850),
                                 RCH=c(910)),
                  tibble(date=as.Date(c("2018/08/01","2018/08/02","2018/08/03","2018/08/04",
                                        "2018/08/05","2018/08/06","2018/08/07"), format="%Y/%m/%d"),
                                 Flow=c(120, 780, 820, 580, 870, 870, 840),
                                RCH=c(910)))
```

I've created a function that creates a graph for each year and plot on it Flows coming from various reaches (here for simplicity I just used a single reach 910). I want to add on the x-axis labels for several specified dates (month and day) that are the same each year. I didn't know how to make it work for every year so instead, I've only added it for year 2015:

```
test_line_plot <- function (x) {
  ggplot(x, aes(date, Flow, group = RCH)) +
    geom_line() + 
    facet_wrap( ~ format(date, "%Y"))+
   scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d", 
         breaks = (as.Date(c("2015/08/04", "2015/08/06"))))+
    theme (panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
    coord_cartesian( ylim = c(0, 1000))
}
```

And I've applied it to my list:

```
test_plot_list <- lapply(Flowtest , test_line_plot)
library("ggpubr")
test_plot <- ggarrange(plotlist = test_plot_list, nrow = 4, ncol = 1)
plot(test_plot)
```

In the resulting graph date labels onx-axis and matching major grid lines only appear in 2015:

[image]

Where I was hoping to achieve something like the one below, where every year has the same date labels and major grid lines marking them. **The main focus here is adding chosen dates (day and month) as x-axis labels for each year (the same every year). Preferably with the use of scale_x_date.**

[image]

How can I change the code in the function (scale_x_date) so it doesnt just apply to 2015 but also any other years in the dataset?

**Also** I don't understand why the graph for 2015 is smaller then the other graphs...

I'll be thankful for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot breaks as date month and day without year, show labels for chosen dates in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69023134/ggplot-breaks-as-date-month-and-day-without-year-show-labels-for-chosen-dates-i)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a vector with your dates and pass them as `breaks` inside `scale_x_date`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

#Example of dates to use as breaks
x_dates <- dmy(c("04/08/15","06/08/15","02/08/17","05/08/18"))
    
Flowtest %>%
  # Make a single data.frame from the list of data.frames
  bind_rows() %>% 
  # Create variable year
  mutate(year = year(date)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, Flow, group = RCH)) +
  geom_line() + 
  # Using year for facet, with free scales and a single column
  facet_wrap(~year,scales = "free", ncol = 1)+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d",breaks = x_dates)+
  theme (panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  coord_cartesian( ylim = c(0, 1000))
```

[image]